# How to merge many CSV files?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have about 7500 csv that needs to be merged into a single one in order to create an easy-readable table.
The files format are as follow:

1. each file is denominated as a ticker of a stock (example: AA.csv, AAL.csv, AAPL.csv,etc...)
2. every file itself contains a date and a number in this format

   ```
   2018-10-11,1
   2018-10-12,3
   2018-10-15,2
   ...
   ```

Now I want to merge them into a single csv file where the resulting table has in the header the name of the tickers, in the first column the dates and following the numbers (obviously keeping the csv format).

Example:

[image: screenshot of example]

Note that some csv files are empty and some have differents starting dates or dates are just discontinued

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834068/pandas-join-not-working-to-combine-sp500-stock-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

dfs_list = []
for csv_file in glob('Tickers List/*.csv'):
    stock_ticker = csv_file.split(".")[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,header=None, names=["date","num"])
    if df.shape[0] >0:
        df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"],format="%Y-%m-%d")
        df["stock_ticker"] = stock_ticker
        dfs_list.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs_list)
```

With `glob('dir/*.csv')` we get all the csv files on a folder.

After this, you will have a DataFrame that looks like this:
[image]

If you want to change to your format, you can do this:
(note that the dates are automatically sorted because is used as index).

```py
final_df = pd.pivot_table(final_df, values='num', index=['date'],
               columns=['stock_ticker'], fill_value=np.nan)
```

And you will have a DataFrame that looks like this:

[image]

Now you can write this DataFrame to a new csv with:

```py
final_df.to_csv("merged.csv")
```

## FULL CODE

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

dfs_list = []
for csv_file in glob('Tickers List/*.csv'):
    stock_ticker = csv_file.split(".")[0]
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,header=None, names=["date","num"])
    if df.shape[0] >0:
        df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"],format="%Y-%m-%d")
        df["stock_ticker"] = stock_ticker
        dfs_list.append(df)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs_list)

final_df = pd.pivot_table(final_df, values='num', index=['date'],
               columns=['stock_ticker'], fill_value=np.nan)

final_df.to_csv("merged.csv")
```

Comment: ["AA.csv","AAL.csv"..] but I need to select all the files in a folder, i can't write them down since they're a lot

Comment: are they all in the same folder?

Comment: Do I need to replace something in the first part? like the dir path?

Comment: You need to change the csvs dir path inside glob.

Comment: I'm a real noob at this sorry. I can't understand how to type the right path i mean with all the \\ and : in the right spot. is there a fast way to do it?

Comment: just with Tickers List

Comment: i modified the code, you have your file in the same folder so you only need to specify the folder name

Comment: Ok, now i got this error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Diego\PycharmProjects\thesis\merge2.py", line 13, in <module>
    columns=['stock_ticker'], fill_value=np.nan)
NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Comment: add import numpy as np at the beginning

Comment: Ok tons of errors now

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Diego\PycharmProjects\thesis\merge2.py", line 13, in <module>
    final_df = pd.pivot_table(final_df, values='num', index=['date'],
  File "C:\Users\Diego\PycharmProjects\thesis\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 113, in pivot_table
    agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)

and counting....

Comment: Try to copy all the trace and make sure you are using the last version of code

Answer (score 0):

Since you have non-uniform csvs, and some specific requirements:

- ***certain format to output the csv***
- some csv files are empty
- some csv files have different start dates
- some csv files have discontinues dates

### I'd do something like this with the `csv` module:

```
import os,csv
csv_dir = "C:\\Users\Diego\\PycharmProjects\\thesis\\Tickers List\\"
csv_out = 'csvout.csv'

all_dates = []
fin_table = dict()

# iterating over all csv files
for csv_file in os.listdir(csv_dir):
    if True:

        csv_name = csv_file #[:-4] # excluding the ".csv" extension 
        table = dict()
        
        print(csv_dir+csv_file)
        with open(csv_dir+csv_file, 'r') as r:
            csvReader = csv.reader(r)

            for i, row in enumerate(csvReader):
                all_dates.append(row[0])
                table[row[0]] = row[1]
        fin_table[csv_name] = table
    

# populating the final csv 
with open(csv_out, 'w+') as w:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(w)

    # adding the header
    input_row = ['Dates']
    for stock, table in iter(sorted(fin_table.items())):
        input_row.append(stock)
    csvWriter.writerow(input_row)

    # Adding the rest of the table by available date 
    # since, some dates may not have a value, as you said   
    for date in sorted(all_dates): 
        
        # adding the date rows and stock values 1 by 1
        input_row = [date]
        for stock, table in iter(sorted(fin_table.items())):
            # NOVALUE will be put in cells  
            # where a value doesn't exist for a date
            input_row.append(table.get(date, 'NOVALUE')) 
        csvWriter.writerow(input_row)

# ************************** end of program code
```

Comment: i got this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Diego\PycharmProjects\thesis\MERGE.py", line 16, in <module>
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as r:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'A.csv'

Maybe thats because file are named just A, AA, without .csv (but they are csv) how can i solve?

Comment: Please replace `csv_dir` variable value with the folder where all csvs are located! Okay, I'll edit the code.Try the new version!

Comment: Same error "No such file or directory: 'A.csv'"
i edited the csv dir path as follow: csv_dir=r'C:\Users\Diego\PycharmProjects\thesis\Tickers List'

i copied and paste the path where the csv files are

Comment: I know what is happening.. I edited the code! The path in line `with open(csv_dir+csv_file, 'r') as r:` needs to be correct. I added a print to detect it! Check the latest code!

Comment: Nope, thats worse. now the error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Diego\PycharmProjects\thesis\MERGE.py", line 17, in <module>
    with open(csv_dir + csv_file, 'r') as r:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Diego\\PycharmProjects\\thesis\\Tickers ListA.csv'

Comment: Yeah, you see the path is not formatted properly "C:\\Users\\Diego\\PycharmProjects\\thesis\\Tickers ListA.csv"... you have to make it "C:\Users\Diego\PycharmProjects\thesis\Tickers List\A.csv"... Try the new version.

Comment: I'm a real noob at this sorry. I can't understand how to type the right path i mean with all the \\ and : in the right spot. is there a fast way to do it?

Comment: You are almost there.... Can you please try the new code! and report the Error!

Comment: File "C:\Users\Diego\PycharmProjects\thesis\MERGE.py", line 3
    csv_dir = r'C:\Users\Diego\PycharmProjects\thesis\Tickers List\'
                                                                  
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal. Again i'm doing something wrong with the path

Comment: Okay, just one more try.... This time I added your path directly in the code!

Comment: it's running.. i'll let you know as soon as it finishes.. i think it's going to take a lot but for now..no errors!

Comment: Great! If it works, please accept the answer by clicking the ✅ button and leave an upvote!

Comment: I think thats something wrong. the code works and it creates an excel file of 11GB. This is weird considering that the 6500 files themeselves weights just about 20 mb but ok. I can't open the excel apparently or it looks like it takes a lot of time. However, opening it as a preview i see only the headers names shown correctly and another white line under the names, are you sure with the code? anyway i wait until its going to open it. Thanks!

Comment: 11GB that's too much! Something is definitely wrong, but as far as I can see the code should work fine!

Comment: Nevermind! the other guy provide me the right code in the end, but thank you, anyway!